# mysql_query does not return anything but the query works fine in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM( usd_amount ) AS value_sum 
     FROM order_tbl 
     WHERE o_date BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 
          DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) -1 ) AND CURDATE()
");

if(!$query){
        echo "Did Not Execute the query";
        echo mysqli_error();
```

}

I keep getting the "Did Not Execute the query" but the query runs fine in phpMyAdmin. The echo for `mysqli_error()` is also not displaying anything.

Also, I have checked the connection and the connection works absolutely correct.

Comment: Perhaps using [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to find out why it didn't execute the query might help

Comment: `mysql_query()` is depricated. Always try to use `mysqli_query()` . Avoid using mysql API. Use mysqli API.

Comment: don't use `mysql_*`, it's deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Anant: Connection object is optional. Real problem is query is [syntactically invalid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order 
     WHERE o_date BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 
          DAYOFMONTH( CU' at line 2

Comment: order is taking as a part of sql keyword not as table_name . please make `order` to `orders`

Comment: Tried using mysqli_query but still getting the same error.Also, the order table has a different name I have changed it here just for privacy issue.

Comment: I have used PDO for connecting to database. and it says that the connection is successful.

Comment: You shouldn't mix `mysql` functions, `mysqli` functions and `PDO`. They are [different APIs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) used to connect to `MySQL` databases. There is nothing wrong (but very unusual) to use two or all three of them in the same project but they **cannot be combined**. If you open your connection with [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) the you have to use the created connection only with [`mysql_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions. The same for the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from comments, and reopened the question since you changed the table's name.

> *"order is taking as a part of sql keyword not as table_name . please make order to orders – Rohan Khude 46 mins ago"*

OP:

> *"Tried using mysqli_query but still getting the same error.Also, the order table has a different name I have changed it here just for privacy issue. – Shweta Soparkar 10 mins ago"*

and:

> *"I have used PDO for connecting to database. and it says that the connection is successful. – Shweta Soparkar 10 mins ago"*

**You cannot mix MySQL APIs, you must use the same one from connecting to querying.**

- **Connect with PDO, query with PDO, nothing else.**

You are using `mysql_query()` then `mysqli_error()` and mixing those together along with PDO.

Since you are using PDO to connect with, then you need to change your query to a PDO method.

Manual reference on querying with PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Error checking references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Other references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php (Choosing an API)
- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Order is a reserved SQL keyword. You can get around this by wrapping it in backticks (`` `order` ``).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html for a full list of reserved keywords in MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
$STH_SELECT = $conn->query("SELECT SUM( usd_amount ) AS value_sum 
     FROM order_tbl 
     WHERE o_date BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 
          DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) -1 ) AND CURDATE()
");
$sof = $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();
echo $sof;
```

Comment: If you are not accessing the result set value by referencing `value_sum`, then there is no point declaring the column alias.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.